# Ant "exec" tag outputproperty value not chaning when calling a "macrodef" from a target twice

Tags: ant

```
<macrodef>
<if>
    <then>
        <exec  executable="python" failonerror="true" outputproperty="result">
        </exec>
    </then>
<else>
        <exec  executable="python" failonerror="true" outputproperty="result">
</else>
</if> </macrodef>
```

I have a code block of macrodef which is called from a  twice but when it is called second time the  property "result" in the outputproperty is holding the old value and not getting replaced with the new value , I am new to ant would appreciate a work around this ..like if there is an alternative to use other than ant property

Comment: Properties in Ant are immutable: once set in the first exec, it cannot be changed.  You could use the output parameter (puts output in a file) instead perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Using the https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html has solved the issue for me as the property defined with local is with in the scope of the tag.

Something like this

```
<sequential>
    <local name="foo"/>
    <property name="foo" value="bar.2"/>
    <echo>Second sequential: foo is ${foo}</echo>
</sequential>
```